# Views filter value based on a selected filter?

Tags: views

I'm trying build a garbage collection website where the user puts in their city, street, and street number and it tells them the day the garbage is picked up. Right now, I've imported about 14000+ addresses using feeds into a data table and have a view with 3 filters with autocomplete. The problem is that the filters are too simple: when you pick your city, the streets aren't narrowed down to just the applicable streets.

Is there a way for the streets filter to only show results based on the city selection? Am I going about this problem the wrong way?

Comment: A found a way to do this using the Views Hacks module: https://drupal.org/project/views_hacks#views_filters_selective . I had to select "Grouped" for the city exposed filter for it to work.

Comment: IN YOUR VIEWS MODULE
TRY THE FOLLOWING STEPS:
VIEWS:
FILTER CRITERIA:
EXPOSED FILTER: STREET [CONDITION MUST BE "AND"]
CHECK[REQUIRED]
AJAX:YES(OPTIONAL)
I HOPE IT WILL HELP??
IF POSSIBLE CHECK THE BASIC->SETTINGS(ADVANCED)